# What is the point of buffer in getline?

Tags: c, buffer, getline

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

I don't understand the point of the second parameter `size_t *n`.

Why would you need a buffer between the input (stdin for example) and the output (some character array).

Also, in the example they provide, `size_t len = 0;`. What is the significance of setting a buffer of size 0?

Comment: The second parameter is the size of the read data, it tell you how much data to read out of the buffer you provided, or the buffer it allocated for you.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Not really; it is the size of the allocated buffer.  The return value is the length of the data (excluding the null byte at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `getline()` is that it can reallocate the buffer it receives.

Given a caller doing

```
 size_t n = some_value();
 char *buffer = malloc(n);
 getline(&buffer, &n, stdin);
```

The caller supplies an initial `buffer` of length `n`.    If `getline()` reallocates, it changes `buffer` so it points at the memory, and changes `n` to record the new length.

Obviously, this assumes that it is valid to do a `realloc()` on `buffer`   i.e. that buffer is either `NULL` or is the value returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.

The significance of setting `n` to zero AND `buffer` to `NULL` is telling `getline()` that it has been given no buffer.   `getline()` will therefore reallocate if it reads anything.

All of this is actually described in the link you referred to.

Comment: Thanks. One last question though, what size unit is passed by n? If n = 1, is that 1 byte of memory allocated?

Comment: It's bytes, just like `sizeof` returns and `malloc()` takes.

Comment: @C.Buffer It says it in the man page you linked to: `*n bytes in size`

Answer (score 0):

`getline()` needs to know if the array is big enough to hold the line that the user has entered. It gets the current size of the array from the `n` parameter. If the array isn't big enough, it reallocates it to the required size. It then updates `*lineptr` and `*n` to the new array and size. Updating `*n` allows the caller to know how big the array is for its future use (such as calling `getline()` in a loop, as in the example).

Remember, C pointers don't include the size of the array they point to. If a function needs to know this, it has to be passed as a parameter.